# rails_admin nested resources

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rails-admin

I have two models Sectors and Holds with has_many - belongs_to relation.

```
class Sector < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :holds, dependent: :destroy, inverse_of: :sector
end
class Hold < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :sector, inverse_of: :holds
end
```

I have created custom action to show nested Holds for the each Sector:

```
class Holds < RailsAdmin::Config::Actions::Base
    RailsAdmin::Config::Actions.register(self)

    register_instance_option :member do
      true
    end

    register_instance_option :link_icon do
      'icon-user'
    end

    register_instance_option :visible? do
      bindings[:abstract_model].model.to_s == "Sector"
    end

    register_instance_option :controller do
      proc do

        @abstract_model = RailsAdmin::AbstractModel.new(Hold)
        @model_config = RailsAdmin::Config::Model.new(Hold)
        @model_config.include_fields :holder_name, :start_date, :end_date
        @objects = @object.holds

        render :index
      end
    end
  end
```

`/sector`
[image: /sector]

But the 'Add new' action is absent:

`/sector/23/holds`
[image: sector/23/holds]
How I can add 'Add New' action and work properly with nested resources?

Comment: If I am correct, you want to crate holds, from your sector forms right?

Comment: @icemelt I want to show a list of holds belongs to the specific sector with 'Add new' action to add new hold for the sector.

Comment: The Show, Edit and Delete actions act on the Sector not the holds, from a UX standpoint is confusing. 
Just saying that going for another approach, for example: creating a "add hold" action to the Sector and then render the holds inside the Show or Edit view of a sector seem simpler.
Rails admin won't bend easily to the approach you want to take.